# install mongocxx on ubuntu 18.04 container

Tags: mongodb, cmake

### background

I'm going to install mongocxx in ubuntu 18.04 container, following [ref1](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/linux/).

I installed requirement following [ref2](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html)

```
apt install libbson-1.0-0 libbson-dev libmongoc-1.0-0 libmongoc-dev
```

Then download mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0 and cmake like

```
cmake ..                                            \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release                      \
    -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1                      \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local       \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Error:

```
BSON_INCLUDE_DIRS does not exist !
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/libbson-1.0/libbson-1.0-config.cmake:33
```

### question

if I manually vim

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/libbson-1.0/libbson-1.0-config.cmake

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/libmongoc-1.0/libmongoc-1.0-config.cmake

As appendix.them_are_install_here shows

another error happen:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
BSON_LIBRARY
    linked by target "bsoncxx_testing" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/bsoncxx
    linked by target "bsoncxx" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/bsoncxx
    linked by target "test_bson" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/bsoncxx/test
    linked by target "mongocxx_mocked" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx
    linked by target "mongocxx" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx
    linked by target "test_logging" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_gridfs_specs" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_instance" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_driver" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_crud_specs" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
MONGOC_LIBRARY
    linked by target "mongocxx_mocked" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx
    linked by target "mongocxx" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx
    linked by target "test_logging" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_gridfs_specs" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_instance" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_driver" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test
    linked by target "test_crud_specs" in directory /root/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/src/mongocxx/test

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

1. Where I did wrong? How can I fix ?
2. What's difference between "apt search libmongoclient-dev" and mongocxx ?

I just find some related, [ref4](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/c-and-c-driver-for-debian-ubuntu-users/2732) show another way to install it. I will try it tomorrow.

If you have any advice, please help. :)

### appendix

#### them_are_install_here

```
root@42c2d968e81e:~/icode/gitroot/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.2.0/build# find /usr -regex '.*mongoc.*so'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoclient.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so
root@42c2d968e81e:~/icode/gopath/src/baidu/AIIB-MIA/data_collector# find /usr -regex '.*bson.*so'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbson-1.0.so
root@42c2d968e81e:~/icode/gopath/src/baidu/AIIB-MIA/data_collector# stat /usr/include/libbson-1.0
  File: /usr/include/libbson-1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by

```
vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/libbson-1.0/libbson-1.0-config.cmake

vim /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/libmongoc-1.0/libmongoc-1.0-config.cmake

cmake ..                                            \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release                      \
    -DBSONCXX_POLY_USE_BOOST=1                      \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/lib       \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib \
    -DBSON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbson-1.0.so \
    -DMONGOC_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmongoc-1.0.so
```

Thanks for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try the section in http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/linux/ that starts with

> Instead of the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH option, users must specify the libmongoc installation directory by using the -DLIBMONGOC_DIR and -DLIBBSON_DIR options:

specifically

```
    -DLIBMONGOC_DIR=/usr/lib             \
    -DLIBBSON_DIR=/usr/lib               \
```

Since your libbson/libmongoc and libmongoc++ are going to end up in different places you need to tell libmongoc++ where libbson and libmongoc are.

You should NOT be editing any of the files installed by your system package manager (anything in /usr). You should also NOT be installing your hand-compiled software into /usr (that's what /usr/local is for).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. 1. I tried your command with/without editing files in /usr , but still the same error.  2. As the document says, DLIBBSON_DIR is for mongo3.1, and this is mongo3.2, so it's why they don't work.